# Create server panel like cPanel

Tags: service, centos, port, cpanel

I have a VPS, Cent OS 6.4 64bit

I want to create a panel (like cPanel) and I want to make it accessible by opening a port (serverip:2082 for example). I have created php files of my own panel but i don't know anything about linux services.

What type of code must I make and where can I put it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no offense, but if you really don't know about linux service you are 99% away from creating your own panel. You first need to understnad that Cpanel not only modify system files to allow hosting and managing database, but it also do all these without playing with system security.

But to start you need a web server that will host your Cpanel. I prefer it to be different from your webserver that host your website, reason? What if your default apache is inaccessible or crash, your panel will crash with it. Then you need to learn Mysql, or database you want to manage through panel, DNS binding, Name servers, regular expression to manage text files of configuration etc.

I know all these because I already built a Cpanel like application, and know it is not easy job especially with this level of question you asked.